# How can I pick up the spores from the mushrooms in the forest?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the forest, there are some mushrooms everywhere, some of them are shimmering.  Apparently there are **Mushroom Spores** and **Glittering Spores** that can be picked up off of them.  If you hit them, a puff of the stuff comes off but nothing is actually gathered.

Is it even possible to pick these up?  If so, will I need certain items?  How can I do it?

**Fi** mentions at some point in the game that you could get some when I returned to the forest but I wasn't really paying attention to what she said on how and never figured out myself.

Comment: The difference between Mushroom Spores and Glittering Spores, in case you're wondering, is that you can use Glittering Spores on a heart to make it into a fairy! There's other uses too, like to paralyze bugs, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pick up the Mushroom Spores using an Empty Bottle.  Just walk up to the mushroom, hit it to knock the spores loose and scoop up the loose spores.

Comment: This is correct. To get spores from a mushroom, use an empty bottle.

Comment: Well traditionally the powder would go into a bag, not a `Bottle` so I would have expected finding a bag to store it in. Trying to pick up stuff with a bottle does a scooping motion (like picking up water on the ground). The powder isn't actually appear on the ground so it seems odd it would work.  Turns out it actually does. Though, I was kinda hoping for an answer that definitively knew, not just pure speculation. But I'll take this as the answer.

Comment: In Zelda, consumables go in bottles.  It's a good rule.

Comment: @Shinrai: Except the (mushroom) powder, which doesn't in A Link to the Past or Link's Awakening.

Comment: @Shinrai They're more like guidelines anyway. Link's awakening didn't even have bottles.