# What can I do with Mushroom/Glittering Spores?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37916/how-can-i-pick-up-the-mushroom-spores-from-the-mushrooms-in-the-forest), I went and tried it; and, while it worked, I can't find a use for them. I can't sell them at the Item Check, and I tried poring them out, and it makes a yellow dust, but I don't know what that does.

I did the one quest after completing the third dungeon where

> That one lady needs them to heal her Loftwing,

but

> her brother gives you some with a free bottle, and as far as I know, my Loftwing can't get hurt.

What is their use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're asking about the plain old **Mushroom Spores**, the spores you get from any plain mushroom, then I'm convinced that they serve no other purpose in the game and only have a one time use.

> Healing **Orielle's**  **Loftwing**

I've done a fair amount of testing and could not find a single use for them.  Everything I've tried it on does absolutely nothing:

- Hearts (On flowers or on their own)
- Rupees (Green, Blue, and Red)
- Ammo (Seeds, Bombs)
- Catchables (Grasshoppers, Hornets, Rhino Beetles, Non-Blue Birds)
- Enemies (ChuChus, Bokoblins, Octorocks, Guays, Babas, Keese)
- Friendly Characters (Kikwis, The old lady in the temple, townspeople)
- Diggable holes
- Breakables (Pots, Bushes, big fruits)
- Other mushrooms (non-sparkling and sparkling)
- Bird Statues
- Other interactive items (Sticky Plant Bombs, Stamina Fruit, Chairs, Ropes, Trees, etc.)

---

If on the other hand you are asking about the **Glittering Spores**, the spores you get from the glittering mushrooms, they have very limited uses AFAIK.  There's only a couple of uses that I know of.

You can use it on **Hearts** or **Rupees** to change them.  **Hearts** turn into **Fairies**.  **Rupees** turn into different valued rupees, even a **Rupoor**.

On some of the smaller enemies, it knocks them dizzy.  I was only able to do this on **Bokoblins**, **Octorocks** and **Babas** (the plants) but didn't have enough to test on others.

Comment: I'm going to go test on a Moblin. Wish me luck. ;)

Comment: No effect on a Moblin. Can you clarify how to use on hearts and rupees? Does it work on heart flowers or free floating hearts?

Comment: You'll have to be standing in front of the item that you want to use it on, just don't touch it otherwise you'll just pick it up.  And it doesn't work on heart flowers AFAIK.

Comment: Actually, it seems this is Glittering Spores, not Mushroom Spores. Do you know of any use for Mushroom Spores?

Comment: They are both one in the same.  I initially called them `Mushroom Spores` in the other question thinking that was the name since you got them from mushrooms in the forest.  In the inventory, they are in fact called **Glittering Spores**.  It's the same exact substance that is given to you when you have to help the Orielle.

Comment: @JefMercado: Are you sure? I thought you only got Glittering Spores from sparkly mushrooms and non-sparkley mushrooms gave you mushroom spores. Because the mushroom spores didn't seem to be doing again.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Do the normal non-sparkly mushrooms give off anything?  I always had the impression that they didn't.  If so and you intended to ask about those, then I'll have to revise my answer.  I'm assuming you are asking about the spores that I asked in that other question, the glittering ones.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I didn't notice there were two types either. I could probably edit it to ask about both.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: I'm starting up the game right now to see if the non-sparkly mushrooms give off anything.  It looks like there are two different kinds...  Revisions are in order.

Comment: I will have to re-test after making sure I get the `glittering` kind.

Answer (score 0):

The Glittering Spores also [stun enemies, slow down bugs](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Glittering_Spores) (useful, before you get good with the net, or upgrade it), and [temporarily make Gossip Stones disappear](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Glittering_Spores). (News to me!)

Answer (score -2):

*Mushroom* spores do nothing. For *glittering* spores read the entries above. But there is something i want to add; at least in master quest, mushrooms are subject to change. I dont know about the first time around though. Can somebody check?

Comment: How exactly does this differ from the accepted answer?